# Cholesky factorization for special matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I was wondering if there's any special technique for finding Cholesky factor a SPD matrix $A$ when it has this form: $$A = I + uu^T$$

Comment: is $u$ anything special like all ones?

Comment: nope. $u$ can be any vector.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Updating_the_decomposition